# window.alert(this) should always be object window?

Tags: javascript, this, alert

As we know,

> When a function is called as a method of an object, its `this` is set to the object the method is called on.

---

added:

the statement above is from this site [this - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

I don't understand is the ***As an object method***,as it said ,"this" is in the method(alert) of object (window),so it should be reference "window" object?

---

Now, my question is:

```
window.alert(this)
```

In this case, `this` is in the method `window.alert`, so it will always return object window.
Is there any wrong in my thought process?

---

update:
      thank you guys so much,I think I nearly understand it:
      when window.alert(this),`this`
 is a parameter,not really a `this` in method.that's my understand.Is it right?

To make sure that, I need to know how the `alert` is defined in javascript. Any idea to guide me read relative document?

Comment: Note carefully what the word "its" refers to.

Comment: There is. `window` is the context for `alert` call. Whereas `this` is a current context.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? `function foo() { window.alert(this); } foo.call(42)`.

Comment: its means this in method of an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.alert(this)` will take the current value of `this` and pass it as an argument to the `alert()` function.  What the current value of `this` is depends entirely upon the context that `window.alert(this)` is inside of.  It may be `window` or it may point to some other object.  We'd have to see the containing code to know for sure.

For example, if you did this:

```
var x = {
   callme: function() {
       alert(this);       // alerts the x object
   }
};

x.callme();
```

Then, the alert would show the `x` object because that's the value of `this` inside of the `callme()` function when called via `x.callme()`.

---

In strict mode in a normal function call, `this` will be `undefined`.  So, it very much depends upon the context:

```
function hello() {
    "use strict";
    alert(this);        // alerts undefined
}

hello();
```

---

Or, not in strict mode:

```
function hello() {
    alert(this);        // alerts the window object (in a browser)
}

hello();
```

Comment: "*What the current value of this is depends entirely upon the context that*..." might be better expressed as "*depends on what this was set to when entering the current execution context*".

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
<div id="that" onclick="window.alert(this.id)">Click me.</div>
```

The object the method (onclick) is called on is the `div` element. It really is determined by the current scope. Perhaps read up on that.

UPDATE:

Here is a similar example where `this`, in two different scopes, will have two different values.

```
var div = document.querySelector('#that');
div.onclick = function() {
    alert(this); // [object HTMLDivElement]
    functionDeclaredInGlobalScope();
}

functionDeclaredInGlobalScope() {
    alert(this); // [object Window]
}
```

When you click that `div`, a method begins executing. That method is `onclick`. The object the method is called on is the `div` as this example makes a bit clearer. So, `this` will be equal to that `div` element. However, inside the `onclick`, we call a function that was defined in the gloabal scope (which means that it is really just a method of `window`). When we start executing `functionDeclaredInGlobalScope` a new scope is created, and `this` is assigned a different value, but it's the same process: The method is `functionDeclaredInGlobalScope` and the object it is called on is `window`. Once you have `this`, you can assign it to a variable, or pass it wherever you want to retain it. For example:

```
div.onclick = function() {
    alert(this); // [object HTMLDivElement]
    functionInGlobalScope(this);
}

functionDeclaredInGlobalScope(that) {
    alert(that); // [object HTMLDivElement]
    alert(this); // [object Window]
}
```

Comment: No, `this` is *not* the "scope".

Comment: I did not say `this` == scope. What I meant is that the value of `this` depends upon the current scope, but I'll edit to make that more clear.

Comment: OK, but that statement is equally wrong. I could go and say `document.getElementById("that").onclick.call({id:"else"})`. The value of `this` only depends on the call, and has nothing to do with scopes.

Comment: What difference does that make? The scope has access to `this`, and it's value is the same until you enter a new scope.

Comment: You created that scope with an explicit value for `this`. If you called the same function directly, it would be a different scope. So...

Comment: Ah, I see what you are getting at: different scope => different `this`. Only many people don't understand that the value of `this` is not determined by *lexical* scoping, but the call that created the *execution context* ("scope").

Comment: I guess you are talking about the scope where the method is called, and I'm talking about the scope inside the method, as it's executing.

Comment: No, I'm really talking about the same scope as you do. The one that is created when the method is called, the one that the `window` variable is looked up in. The execution context that knows the value for the `this` keyword

Comment: To some, "current scope" means "current execution context", the use of "scope" might be misleading or confusing with the wider meaning of the scope chain.

Comment: "The object the method (onclick) is called on is the div element.",how about window.alert?Is that alert is a method,and "this" is in a method of object?

Comment: @JuneWenston, I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but I'll update my answer with something that I think will address it.

Comment: thank you very much,I'd like to accept your answer,but I learned this through another answer.and I like your answer too,I will follow you